# moment(to).toDate() returns a day earlier in momentjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, momentjs

I am trying to match a specific date that a user can select from a date picker with my mongoDB, but when i put `moment(to).toDate()` a returns for me the date -1 days.

for instance `moment(10-25-2021).toDate()` logs `2021-10-24T21:00:00.000Z`
Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
                let _from = moment(from).toDate()
                let _to = moment(to).toDate()

db.collection("Users").find({'from': {$eq: _from },
                        'to': {$eq: _to }})
```

Comment: which locale have you configured?

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment i did not configure any locale.

Comment: I think it could be a problem with your configured or default timezone? Maybe check this: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: "10-25-2021" is not a format supported by moment.js so it falls back to the built–in parser. That format isn't supported by ECMA-262 either, so parsing is implementation dependent. In Safari it returns an invalid date. If parsed as 25 Oct 2021, then it will assume the host offset when generating a time value. "2021-10-24T21:00:00.000Z" is the UTC equivalent and indicates that the host offset for that date was +3:00, so the UTC time is 3 hours earlier (and hence in the previous day).

Answer (score -1):

Check the difference:

```
console.log(moment('10-25-2021').format());
console.log(moment('10-25-2021').utc().format());
```

First one returns date in your(user's) local timezone, second returns it in global UTC(UTC+0) timezone (ISO-8601 format). It's important to understand that when sending dates to server, dates which sent to server usually should be in server's timezone (ideally in UTC+0 for global projects).

Comment: And what do you make of the deprecation warning in the console from the code? You might as well have written `new Date('10-25-2021').toString()` and `new Date('10-25-2021').toISOString()`. In both cases the timestamp is parsed as local and in some implementations returns an invalid date.

Comment: @RobG "10-25-2021" is kinda wrong format, better to use ISO's "2021-10-25" or full ISO version "2021-10-25T00:00:00.000Z" to be sure about timezones.

Comment: Yes, it is "wrong format" which is why there is a large warning in the console. The format should be provided to moment's parser, otherwise it falls back to the built–in parser so you're using the library formatting only, not parsing.